# How can do use maven through a proxy

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-ldap

I want to use maven throught a proxy I read many answers that say to write some configuration in a settings.xml file in the .m2 folder but it's not work this is my configuration : 
**my domaine name is : cgi.net.intra** and 
**my computer is a member of an LDAP**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>ncproxy3</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>gh40615</username>
      <password>mypasseword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

can someone help me ? Merci d'avance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check that your proxy does indeed use http, not https
2. Check that your proxy does indeed use port 8080
3. Use the FQH for  -- ncproxy3.cgi.net.intra
4. Make sure your settings.xml is located in ${user.home}/.m2/

Good luck.

Comment: I will try , Thank you